# Cannot resolve method 'buildAsync()'

Tags: java, gradle, discord-jda

I used to develop bot on JavaScript, but because I code a lot on C++, I decided to move to Java. I found a tutorial and they told me to use Gradle. I followed the instructions and now have this code:

```
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;

import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException {
        JDABuilder builder = new JDABuilder(AccountType.BOT);
        String token = "Not telling";
        builder.setToken(token);
        builder.buildAsync();
    }
}
```

But here the message I get from the compiler when I run it:

```
Error:(11, 16) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method buildAsync()
  location: variable builder of type net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder
```

P.S. here is build.gradle if needed:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'com.discord-bot'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'net.dv8tion:JDA:4.ALPHA.0_67'
}
```

Any suggestion about what to do with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `buildAsync()` was deprecated and removed in version 4 of `net.dv8tion:JDA`.

Since you are using version `4.ALPHA.0_67` of `net.dv8tion:JDA`, you have to use the `build()` method instead:

```
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;

import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException {
        JDABuilder builder = new JDABuilder(AccountType.BOT);
        String token = "Not telling";
        builder.setToken(token);
        builder.build();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can downgrade your version to `net.dv8tion:JDA:3.8.3_462`. But then you have to change some of the imports, since they were changed as well.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Javadoc for the version. You are using 4.0-alpha. This method might be removed in the version you used.

Answer (score 0):

currently jda 4.2.0 changes a bunch of things so the code would look more like

```
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;

import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException {
        JDABuilder builder = JDABuilder.createDefault("your token");

        builder.build();
    }
}
```